# What a L"string" in front of square brackets mean?

Tags: c++, windows-console

I found this among a supposedly trivial Tetris console game code.

```
wchar_t *screen = new wchar_t[];
unsigned char *pField;
.
.
.
screen[someMathIndex] = L" ABCDEFG=#"[pField[someOtherMathIndex]];
```

What is an wchar string in front of square brackets even mean?
I can't even able to find a way to google it.
Can you redirect me to some resource of this strange thing maybe.

Comment: it's getting a wide char out of the string `L" ABCDEFG=#"` at the index `pField[someOtherMathIndex]`

Comment: The complete list of Microsoft C++ prefixes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/string-and-character-literals-cpp

Comment: Note that `new wchar_t[];` is not valid C++. You have to specify the size of the array being allocated, eg: `wchar_t *screen = new wchar_t[SomeSizeHere];`

Comment: Yes it is specified in the actual code...I omitted it actually.

Comment: The same as `pField[someOtherMathIndex][L" ABCDEFG=#"]` of course.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

String literals in C++ are actually arrays.  I this case `L" ABCDEFG=#"` is a `const wchar_t[11]`.  When you do

```
L" ABCDEFG=#"[pField[someOtherMathIndex]]
```

You are going to the `pField[someOtherMathIndex]`'th index of that wchar_t array.

Comment: Never seen this. Thank you very much.

Comment: @MILO No problem.  I've never seen someone do this either.  Typically that string literal would be in a named variable like `wchar_t CoolString[] = L" ABCDEFG=#";` and then you would just have in the code `CoolString[pField[someOtherMathIndex]]`